# EF Core DiagnosticListener not triggered

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to identify long running queries. My EF Core version is 2.1, so interceptors are not available. I found this solution with diagnostics and trying to implement it:

```
public class LongQueryInterceptor
{
    private DateTimeOffset _startTime;
    private string _query;
    private readonly ILogger<LongQueryInterceptor> _logger;
    public LongQueryInterceptor(ILogger<LongQueryInterceptor> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [DiagnosticName("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command.CommandExecuting")]
    public void OnCommandExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, Guid commandId, Guid connectionId, bool async, DateTimeOffset startTime)
    {
        _startTime = startTime;
        _query = command.CommandText;
    }

    [DiagnosticName("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command.CommandExecuted")]
    public void OnCommandExecuted(object result, bool async)
    {
        var endTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        var queryTiming = (endTime - _startTime).TotalSeconds;
        if (queryTiming >= 10)
            _logger.LogInformation("\n" + "Executes " + "\n" + _query + "\n" + "in " + queryTiming + " seconds\n");
    }

    [DiagnosticName("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command.CommandError")]
    public void OnCommandError(Exception exception, bool async)
    {
        _logger.LogError(exception.Message);
    }
}
```

and in startup:

```
        var loggerQueryInterceptor = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<ILogger<LongQueryInterceptor>>();
        var dbContext = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        var listener = dbContext.GetService<DiagnosticSource>();
        (listener as DiagnosticListener).SubscribeWithAdapter(new LongQueryInterceptor(loggerQueryInterceptor));
```

When I put a breakpoint in `OnCommandExecuting` or `OnCommandExecuted` it's not triggered.
Does it attach listener only to this specific instance of DbContext? If so, how can I make it global? And is there any other way to do it?